# AngularJS: ngTable with json data: filtering and sorting does not work

Tags: json, angularjs, sorting, filtering, ngtable

I'm trying to populate data from a REST webservice in a table using ngTable.
Data are shown, but they are neither sortable nor filterable. Filtering always returns empty list.

Here is a link to the API I am referencing: http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/

**JS:**

```
$scope.dataInstances = [];
$scope.getDataInstances = function() {
    $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : '/rest/v1/data/instances',
        headers : {
            "Authorization" : "Basic " + btoa("USERNAME" + ":" + "PASSWORD")
        },
    })
    .success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.dataInstances = data;
        $scope.tableParams.reload();
        // just some logging 
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    })
    .error(function(data, status) {
        alert("Error: " + status);
    });
};
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,     // show first page
        count: 10,   // count per page
        filter: {
        },
        sorting: {
            date: 'asc'     // initial sorting
        }
    }, 
    {
        total: $scope.dataInstances.length, // length of data
        getData: function($defer, params) {
            // use build-in angular filter
            var filteredData = params.filter() ?
                    $filter('filter')($scope.dataInstances, params.filter()) :
                        $scope.dataInstances;
            var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                    $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) :
                        $scope.dataInstances;
            params.total(orderedData.length); // set total for recalc pagination
            $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="myController" ng-init="getDataInstances()">
  <table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table table-condensed">
    <tr ng-repeat="dataInstance in dataInstances">
      <td data-title="'Name'" sortable="'name'" filter="{ 'name' : 'text'}">{{dataInstance.name}}</td>
      <td data-title="'Date'" sortable="'date'" filter="{ 'date' : 'text'}">{{dataInstance.date | date:'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm' }}</td>
      <td data-title="'Type'" sortable="'type'" filter="{ 'type' : 'text'}">{{dataInstance.type}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

You have any hints how to get this working? 
Tried different other possible solutions - and none worked - like:

- [asynchronously populating an AngularJS ngTable with json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22349635/asynchronously-populating-an-angularjs-ngtable-with-json-data)
- [Loading JSON via AJAX with NgTable parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805734/loading-json-via-ajax-with-ngtable-parameters)
- [Sorting ngTable doesn't work when heading gets clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047342/sorting-ngtable-doesnt-work-when-heading-gets-clicked)

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: http://plnkr.co/edit/1Rp9szNtw8T3GtwpNaZG?p=preview

Comment: is filtering and sorting work for `type` and `name` columns?

Comment: No. It does not work in general.

Comment: plunk will be usefull here,can you set up it?

Comment: edited post with link to plunk

Comment: its great trick , works fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

Finally got things working with `angular 1.2.20` and `ng-Table 0.3.1`.

Just have a look at the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4sfqSObIyvnqvnIdyPy3): Sorting and filtering over nested json objects and dates.

Thanks to [Kostia Mololkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4104866/kostia-mololkin) for his efforts!

Answer (score 1):

you need to apply `ng-repeat` directive to `$data` variable,wich is used by `ngtable`

```
<tr ng-repeat="dataInstance in $data">
            <td data-title="'Name'" sortable="'name'" filter="{ 'name' : 'text'}">{{dataInstance.name}}</td>
            <td data-title="'Date'" sortable="'date'" filter="{ 'date' : 'text'}">{{dataInstance.date | date:'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm' }}</td>
            <td data-title="'Type'" sortable="'type'" filter="{ 'type' : 'text'}">{{dataInstance.type}}</td>
          </tr>
```

### Edit

#### Sorting

i got it what's going on the `params.orderBy()` produce this sting for example `"-type"` and `$filter("OrderBy")` can not parse this,this need just `"type"` string and if you want reverse you have to do `$filter('orderBy')(filteredData, "type",-1)` this string

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Played with this. Sorting works for me only the first click. Filtering does still not work. But your explanation that `ngTable` uses `$data` as variable was helpful.

Comment: Updated Plunk with a few more data. Filtering works - i hav no idea why. Filtering `date` returns not the initially expected values: the date filter works on the timestamp from `json` and not on the formatted date string. Any idea how to fix that too?

Comment: let me look what to do with time

Comment: i got it you have to specify custom array filter for collection to do this, some good explanation here http://toddmotto.com/everything-about-custom-filters-in-angular-js/

Comment: i will make plunk for that a little bit later

Answer (score 0):

Got this running.
Seems that there are huge differences using different versions of ng-Table and angular.js.
`angular 1.2.20` and `ng-Table 0.3.0` are working well together on non nested json data.

`angular 1.2.20` and `ng-Table 0.3.1` does well the sorting of nested data but not filtering ([Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/4sfqSObIyvnqvnIdyPy3?p=preview))

Any solutions to this?

**Edit**: `angular 1.2.3` and `ng-Table 0.3.1` would be the solution, but I have to use `angular 1.2.20`