# ng-table pagination, sorting and filter not working

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am trying to use ngTable but its not working as expected.
I've implemented pagination, sorting and filter

Here is a [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/soZVn6j4oNtlsE7EsLIW/preview) i have created.

I have done same way as specified in the [docs](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/1) examples. The pagination, sorting and filter are not working.

I tried to debug but i am not getting any error messages also

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26306998/angularjs-ngtable-with-json-data-filtering-and-sorting-does-not-work/26314238#26314238 please have a look here first you need to apply ng-repeat directive to $data variable ,like <tr ng-repeat="g in $data">

Comment: I have updated the plunker with $filter.Still the same issue

Comment: right,filter still not working,let me figure out a little bit

Comment: you not update repeat in  $data

Comment: does it have to be $data only? The variable name i have used is `tabledata`. I am using `$tabledata` in the view

Comment: Unfortunately only `$data` ,otherwise it will be strange behavior,but that's not big deal,cause you can put all data access logic for `tabledata` inside `getData` function

Comment: you can bind `$tabledata`  for view needing after `ngtable` resolving

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first inject `$filter` in controller

```
controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $filter, ngTableParams) {
```

second, you need to apply `ng-repeat` to `$data` variable like this
`<tr ng-repeat="g in $data">`

### Update

here working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/CbmbXTXukNxC1ZzkJNKO?p=preview), with all edits above, and `angular 1.2.26` and `ngtable 0.3.1`

### Update2

you can bind `$scope.tabledata` if your view is needed,after data retrieving in `getData` function

```
getData: function($defer, params) {
                    // use build-in angular filter
                     filteredData = params.filter() ?
                      $filter('filter')(tabledata, params.filter()) :
                         tabledata;
                 
                    var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                                        $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) : filteredData;
                    var page=orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
                    $scope.tabledata=page;
                    $defer.resolve(page);
                }
```

Comment: thanks to  @Sebastian http://stackoverflow.com/users/3111930/sebastian for formatting

Comment: You're welcome. You should use the editor functions for adding links (the globe with the green arrow to the right) :-).

Answer (score 7):

I'm using a later version of ng-table but was having similar problems. Apparently you need to add `show-filter="true"` to the table tag. I didn't see this in the documentation/examples for ng-table but found it in the source code tests.

My Angular Version :  1.2.16
My ng-Table Version : 0.8.3

*also tried it with*

Angular Version : 1.2.28
ng-Table Version : 0.4.3

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr ng-repeat="candidate in $data">
            <td data-title="'First Name'" filter="{firstName : 'text'}">{{candidate.firstName}}</td>
            <td data-title="'Last Name'"  filter="{lastName  : 'text'}">{{candidate.lastName}}</
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JS Controller**

```
controller: function ($scope, Candidates, NgTableParams) {
            var tableParams = {
                count : 15
            };
            var tableSettings = {

            };
            Candidates.getCandidates().then(function (res) {
                tableSettings.data = res.data._embedded.candidates;
                $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams(tableParams, tableSettings);
            });
        }
```