# How to implement ng-bootstrap 4 table sorting, pagination and filtering

Tags: angular, datatables, ng-bootstrap

I am going through the [official documentation of ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/table/overview), in some of their official examples, the code is not working. In particular I am talking about [this](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/table/examples#sortable) and [this](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/table/examples#complete) examples, when you open them in stackblitz. This makes it hard for me to understand how the code works so that I can implement it my way.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361322/ng-table-pagination-sorting-and-filter-not-working) but the answer is outdated as it is for angularjs.

So now my questions is:

1. How can I implement ng-bootstrap 4 table sorting, pagination and filtering as shown [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/table/examples#complete)? What is the issue with the given code why is it not working?

A working example would be great as it would help me see and understand how the code works. Thank you.

Comment: @AkberIqbal if you go to the links you'll see the stackblitz code. My issue was that the given code wasn't working correctly but I have solved it. Cheers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally have a solution. I went to [their github](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap) to check the issues and [someone confirmed that indeed the stackblitz code has an issue](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/pull/2917#issuecomment-459335702) but gave the source code and a work-around.

**Here is [the working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngbootstrap-table?file=app/app.module.ts)** of an ng-bootstrap 4 table with sorting, pagination and filtering.

I basically organised the code and added a few things that were omitted in the [original stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/angular/eqvvjjolork).

Among the issues that were there, was that the directive wasn't declared in the declarations' array in AppModule.

Comment: do you know how to add column lvl dropdown filter?

Answer (score 0):

I came across the search feature and solved it like below:
Search and filering solution (Not working part):

```
 constructor(pipe: DecimalPipe) {
    this.countries$ = this.filter.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(text => search(text, pipe))
    );
  }
}
```

The valueChanges would emit to a subscription, so if you change the code like below to subscribe to the changes:

```
constructor(pipe: DecimalPipe) {
    this.filter.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(text => {
         this.countries$ = search(text, pipe))
      }
    ).subscribe();
  }
}
```

Also, change the search method to return you a Observable instead of the array like below:

```
search(text: string, pipe: PipeTransform): Observable<Country[]> {
  return Observable.of(COUNTRIES.filter(country => {
    const term = text.toLowerCase();
    return country.name.toLowerCase().includes(term)
        || pipe.transform(country.area).includes(term)
        || pipe.transform(country.population).includes(term);
  }));
}
```

this should work.