# Angular 8 ng-bootstrap 5 table sorting not working

Tags: angular, sorting, html-table, angular8, ng-bootstrap

I have a project which is using .NET Core 3.1 and Angular 8 (`"@angular/core": "8.2.12"`).
The part of getting and subscribing data from Web API is working well.
Now I am trying to perform a sortable, pagination, and filtering table, so I find [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/table/examples#complete) and the [working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngbootstrap-table?file=app/app.module.ts) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54700298/how-to-implement-ng-bootstrap-4-table-sorting-pagination-and-filtering/54707792).

Following the setup, I run the install cmd in PowerShell:

```
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@5.3.1
```

add this to my app.module.ts:

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgbModule
  ]
```

and then I tried to follow the working code to add sort function to my table, but I can't click the header to sort the data.

so I copied these files from the working code to my project:

- countries.ts
- country.service.ts
- country.ts
- sortable.directive.ts
- table-complete.html
- table-complete.ts

and set route and declarations for table-complete.html page in my app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NgbdTableComponent
  ],
  providers: [AppComponent, NgbdTableComponent, NgbdSortableHeader]
```

(I change the class name from NgbdTableComplete to NgbdTableComponent)

Here is the screenshot:
[The pagination and filtering functions are working well.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bcDi.png)

But I still cannot click the table header to sort the table.
Did I miss something during the process?

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducible example of what you did in stackblitz ?

Comment: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kuubks) I tried to build an example but its appearance is different. As a result, I still cannot click the table header to sort the data. What I confused about is that the code is the same as [working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngbootstrap-table?file=app/app.module.ts), the only difference is angular version. But I checked [update guide](https://update.angular.io/#7.0:8.2), it seems it has nothing to do with version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Components/directives/pipes should be added to declarations array of app.module as shown below

  ```
   @NgModule({
   declarations: [
   AppComponent, 
   NgbdTableComponent, 
   NgbdSortableHeader
   ],
   imports:[BrowserModule, 
            HttpClientModule, 
            NgbModule
            ],
   providers: [] 
   })
  ```
- include below css from [working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngbootstrap-table?file=styles.css) (styles.css) to display sort arrow

  ```
  th[sortable] 
    {
     cursor: pointer;
     user-select: none;
     -webkit-user-select: none;
     }

   th[sortable].desc:before, th[sortable].asc:before {
     content: '';
     display: block;
     background: url('data:image/png;base64,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') no-repeat;
     background-size: 22px;
     width: 22px;
     height: 22px;
     float: left;
     margin-left: -22px;
   }

   th[sortable].desc:before {
     transform: rotate(180deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
   }
  ```

Comment: You're right! After added NgbdSortableHeader to declarations array, everything is working! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped!